# Tracking Users Login and Logout with Session in ASP.Net and present in a report

Tags: asp.net, session

I have an application in which I want to design a Login Logout report for all the users.If in a day user login twice in the application then report should display two records pertaining to that user. The report should have the following details : 
1. User ID 
2. User Name 
3. Login date & time 
4. Logout date & time 
5. Logout reason –
E.g. ‘User Logged out’ or ‘System Logged out’ etc.
6. IP address of the machine

Any suggestions on how can I accomplish this?
Thank you

Comment: What have you done so far? Check this link out if you don't know what I mean. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask